# renegotiated master key in openssl s_client

Tags: openssl, secure-renegotiation

OpenSSL c_client (CLI) prints the Master-Key during initial handshake. This can be clubbed with client random to decrypt packet capture in Wireshark. However, the random and master key changes after renegotiation and packet decryption stops working after this.

Is there a way to print the Master-Key after secure re-negotiation as well (from command line client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is not supported in s_client. However, the renegotiated keys can be printed by hijacking the `SSL_read` function in `ssl/ssl_lib.c` file of openssl library.

I added the following code to `SSL_read()`.

```
int i;
printf("key is: ");
for(i=0;i<48;i++){
  printf("%.2X",s->session->master_key[i]);
}    
printf("\n");
```

Then I ran `apps/openssl s_client` with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` to print the keys used for each read operation.

Note: re-negotiated key based decryption is not supported in older versions of Wireshark. I used `Wireshark-win64-2.3.0-3548-gc30bb2c`